# Setting initial values on load with Select2 with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have select2 controls set up with Ajax (have both single and multiple).  I'm trying to have some values on page load but I'm not able to get this to work however.  My code for select2 is given below:

```
function AjaxCombo(element, url, multival ){  // multival = true or false
  multival = multival || false;
  $(element).select2({
   minimumInputLength: 2,
   multiple: multival,
   separator: '|',
   ajax: {
     url: url,
     dataType: 'json',
     data: function (term, page) {
        var targetname = $(this).attr('name');
        var target = targetname.slice(targetname.indexOf("[")+1, targetname.indexOf("]"));
       return {
         targettype: "search",
         target: target,
         search: term
       };
     },
     results: function (data, page) {
       return { results: data };
     }
   }
 });
}
AjaxCombo(".ajaxselect", "includes/linkedcontrol.php", false);
AjaxCombo(".ajaxmultiselect", "includes/linkedcontrol.php", true);
```

The Ajax combo works fine, am having trouble only with the initial values load.  I tried this code below but couldn't get it to work:

```
initSelection : function (element, callback) {
    var elementText = $(element).attr('data-initvalue');
    callback(elementText);
}
```

My HTML from php is returned as below :

```
<input name='header[country]' class='ajaxselect'  data-initvalue='[{"id":"IN","name":"India"}]' data-placeholder='Select Country' value='' />
```

I see that values are populated from php, only my jquery is having issues. My values in the control show up as `US | United States of America`.  I guess I have edited the select2 source for getting this format as default without using format option.

Can anyone please help me populate the default values?  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** This question pertains to Select2 version <4.0.  This option is removed from v4.0 and is much simpler now.

Comment: look at `initSelection` option

Comment: I had tried that without success (pls chk my description).  do you see any issues in how I did? can you help me clear that?

Comment: Try `callback(JSON.parse(elementText));`

Comment: Try to replace `data-initvalue` with `value` and use `callback(JSON.parse(elementText));` in `initSelection`.

Comment: @user1983983 Thank you so much. Your suggestion did the trick. I replaced `var elementText = JSON.parse($(element).val());` instead of changing the callback. You didn't put your suggestion as answer, so I can't mark your answer as accepted one but I have upvoted it.

Comment: You are welcome, I added my suggestion as an answer. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function which you are specifying as `initSelection` is called with the initial `value` as argument. So if `value` is empty, the function is not called.
When you specifiy `value='[{"id":"IN","name":"India"}]'` instead of `data-initvalue` the function gets called and the selection can get initialized.

Comment: I have an issue with using the value attribute as this gets submitted even with blank. i tried to keep it blank and pull this dynamically from data-initvalue in the select2 params but that does not work.  is there a way i can do without defining the value attribute?

Comment: What do you mean by it gets submitted even with blank? When you clear the value, the initially specified value gets submitted?

Comment: Do you mean `initSelection`?

Comment: it only displays blank or empty

Answer (score 24):

Maybe this work for you!!
This works for me...

```
initSelection: function (element, callback) {

            callback({ id: 1, text: 'Text' });
}
```

Check very well that code is correctly spelled, my issue was in the `initSelection`, I had `initselection`

Comment: `initSelection` is **Deprecated in Select2 4.0**. This has been replaced by the **`current`** method on the _data adapter_ and is only **available in the full builds**.

Comment: @PaulT.Rawkeen so the ability to have a pre-selection has been deprecated and made more confusing?  wtf?  I've been trying to pre-select multiple values for hours now and never saw that in the docs.  This is absurd.

Comment: Doesn't help that half of the documentation is "being written". Honestly, if you haven't written the documentation yet, the version is not ready to be released.

Answer (score 15):

**Updated** to new version:

Try this solution from here http://jsfiddle.net/EE9RG/430/

```
$('#sel2').select2({
multiple:true,
ajax:{}}).select2({"data": 
     [{"id":"2127","text":"Henry Ford"},{"id":"2199","text":"Tom Phillips"}]});
```

Comment: Is there a way to add an `if` on this callback?

Comment: i had a problem with the plugin, only adds the first array, ignore the rest of them

Comment: The AJAX call doesn't happen.

Answer (score 14):

Ravi, for 4.0.1-rc.1:

1. Add all `<option>` elements inside `<select>`.
2. call `$element.val(yourarray).trigger("change");` after `select2` init function.

HTML:

```
<select name="Tags" id="Tags" class="form-control input-lg select2" multiple="multiple">
       <option value="1">tag 1</option>
       <option value="2">tag 2</option>
       <option value="3">tag 3</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
var $tagsControl = $("#Tags").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '/Tags/Search',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            results: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.text,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: false
        },
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        maximumSelectionLength: 6
    });

    var data = [];
    var tags = $("#Tags option").each(function () {
        data.push($(this).val());
    });
    $tagsControl.val(data).trigger("change");
```

This issue was reported but it still opened.
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3116#issuecomment-146568753

Comment: NOTE: I also try to directly push it without add in option, but it's not work. You should add in both option and push + trigger

Comment: Struggled for 3 hours before stumbling upon this sweet piece of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

A very weird way for passing data. I prefer to get a JSON string/object from server and then assign values and stuff.

Anyway, when you do this `var elementText = $(element).attr('data-initvalue');` you're getting this `[{"id":"IN","name":"India"}]`. That result you must PARSE it as suggested above so you can get the real vales for id ("IN") and name("India"). Now there are two scenarios, multi-select & single-value Select2.

Single Values:

```
$(element).select2({
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = {id: "IN", text: "INDIA"};
        callback(data);
    }//Then the rest of your configurations (e.g.: ajax, allowClear, etc.)
});
```

Multi-Select

```
$("#tags").select2({
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var countryId = "IN"; //Your values that somehow you parsed them
        var countryText = "INDIA";

        var data = [];//Array

        data.push({id: countryId, text: countryText});//Push values to data array


        callback(data); //Fill'em
    }
});
```

NOW HERE'S THE TRICK! Like belov91 suggested, you MUST put this...

```
$(element).select2("val", []);
```

Even if it's a single or multi-valued Select2. On the other hand remember that you can't assign the Select2 ajax function to a `<select>` tag, it must be an `<input>`.

Hope that helped you (or someone).

Bye.

Answer (score 5):

I`ve added

```
initSelection: function (element, callback) {

      callback({ id: 1, text: 'Text' });
}
```

**BUT also**

```
.select2('val', []);
```

at the end.

This solved my issue.

Comment: A question after more than a year; why exactly is that `.select2('val', [])` part is necessary? I'm a little too lazy to go through the source code.

Comment: @Hkan This is required to clear out the current value in the field. Otherwise the select2 will append the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = $("#container").find("[name=elemMutliOption]");
for (var i = 0; i < arrDynamicList.length; i++)
{
   elem.find("option[value=" + arrDynamicList[i] + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
}
elem.select2().trigger("change");
```

This will work for people who are using the same view for multiple section in the page, with that being said it will work the same way for auto-setting defaults in your page OR better a EDIT page.

The "FOR" goes through the array that has existing options already loaded in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value after the page loads

`$('#data').val('').change();`

Answer (score 1):

These answer are pretty outdated.  Some work in certain situations, but this is in the documentation. https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2

Basically you need create and append the selected options.

```
// Set up the Select2 control
$('#mySelect2').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/students'
    }
});

// Fetch the preselected item, and add to the control
var studentSelect = $('#mySelect2');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/students/s/' + studentId
}).then(function (data) {
    // create the option and append to Select2
    var option = new Option(data.full_name, data.id, true, true);
    studentSelect.append(option).trigger('change');

    // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
    studentSelect.trigger({
        type: 'select2:select',
        params: {
            data: data
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
$(element).select2("data",[ { id: result.id, text: "جابر احمد الصباح" },
    { id: 2, text: "خليل محمد خليل" }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was rendering the output.. So I used the default  text if the ajax data is not present yet.

```
  templateSelection: function(data) {
    return data.name || data.element.innerText;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late :( but I think this will solve your problem.

```
 $("#controlId").val(SampleData [0].id).trigger("change");
```

After the data binding

```
 $("#controlId").select2({
        placeholder:"Select somthing",
        data: SampleData // data from ajax controll
    });
    $("#controlId").val(SampleData[0].id).trigger("change");
```