# Populate Select2 with AJAX data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 4.0.0-rc.2.

The [Options page](https://select2.github.io/options.html#initSelection) states the following about `initSelection`

> In the past, Select2 required an option called `initSelection` that was defined whenever a custom data source was being used, allowing for the initial selection for the component to be determined. This has been replaced by the `current` method on the [data adapter](https://select2.github.io/options.html#dataAdapter).

I only found examples for older versions of Select2 that use `initSelection` (see [Setting initial values on load with Select2 with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699641/setting-initial-values-on-load-with-select2-with-ajax))

How can I load default data with data adapter?

here is my initial code (is twig)

```
 $("#{{ id }}").select2({
            ajax: {
                    url: "{{ path(attr.path) }}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    {% if attr.placeholder is defined %}
                    placeholder: '{{ attr.placeholder }}',
                    {% endif %}
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (term) {
                        return term;
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {results: data};
                    }

                },
            templateResult: function(data){
                return '<img width="30" src="'+data.image+'">'+data.text;
            },
            templateSelection: function(data){
                return '<img width="30" src="'+data.image+'">'+data.text;
            },

            cache: true,
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
            minimumInputLength: 2
        });
```

If it possible i want setup always visible options and have ajax other,

Answer (score 5):

```
<select id="posow"></select>
```

for above select i do like this:

```
$(function () {
            $.getJSON( "/f3/tokenize/PO_SoW", function(respond) {
                $('#posow').select2({
                    multiple: true,
                    data: respond
                });
             });
});
```

respond from server is this:

```
[{id: 'nms', text: 'FATP'},
{id: 'nms', text: 'ATF Plan'},
{id: 'nms', text: 'Endorse Plan'},
{id: 'nms', text: 'Endorse Date'}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a detailed explanation [on their docs](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#removed-initselection). If you only need to load your data once you can do that using the following code (that was stripped from their docs page):

```
var $element = $('select').select2(); // the select element you are working with

var $request = $.ajax({
  url: '/my/remote/source' // wherever your data is actually coming from
});

$request.then(function (data) {
  // This assumes that the data comes back as an array of data objects
  // The idea is that you are using the same callback as the old `initSelection`

  for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
    var item = data[d];

    // Create the DOM option that is pre-selected by default
    var option = new Option(data.text, data.id, true, true);

    // Append it to the select
    $element.append(option);
  }

  // Update the selected options that are displayed
  $element.trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: i want setup initial data to ajax input, i read doc but dont know how to do it. i add my setup code.

Comment: Yeah, docs are not great IMHO. How in the world do you even use (add) an adapter? Are there docs for the config on this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to code / add an adapter?  I don't get how custom data adapters support AJAX, as the whole point of AJAX is to only fire the callback when the requests are done.  I am probably just not as smart as the guy who designed this?

Comment: Well done! It works. Only be careful: var option = new Option(item.text, item.id, true, true);

Answer (score 0):

As a continuation of Milz's answer I would add that you need to append an empty value at the end otherwise the last value will never be selected.

```
  ...

  for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
    var item = data[d];

    // Create the DOM option that is pre-selected by default
    var option = new Option(data.text, data.id, true, true);

    // Append it to the select
    $element.append(option);
  }

  var option = new Option('', '', true, true);
  $element.append(option);

  ...
```

Maybe there is some other way to do it but this did the trick for me.