# Jquery select2 prefill data issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I want to prefill the datas in the select2

Here is the response from server

https://jsfiddle.net/j6tv52s6/

How can i do the prefill to the select ?

[image]

Here is my [Fiddle][2]

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name='zipcode_covered' id='zipcodeCollection' value="">
<select class="js-data-example-ajax" style="width:100%" multiple="multiple" placeholder='Pincode'></select>
```

Here is the Script :

```
function formatRepo(repo) {
  if (repo.loading) return repo.text;
  var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +
               '<div clas="col-sm-10">' +
               '<div class="clearfix">' +
               '<div class="col-sm-6">' + repo.zipcode + '</div>' +
               '</div>'
  markup += '</div></div>';
  return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
  var cur_val = $('#zipcodeCollection').val();
  if (cur_val) {
    $('#zipcodeCollection').val(cur_val + "," + repo.zipcode);
  } else {
    $('#zipcodeCollection').val(repo.zipcode);
  } 
  return repo.zipcode;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "getZipList",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      delay: 250,
      data: function(params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, page) {
        return {
          results: data.items
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page  
  });
});
```

Comment: Please do a quick search before posting a question.
Ref:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749891/populate-select2-with-ajax-data

https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#removed-initselection

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly.. You want to fill a select drop down with options from the server?

Here is how you would do it with ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (domain) {
            $.each(domain.ZipCodes, function (index, value) {
                    $("#zipcodeDropdown").append(
                        $("<option></option>").text(value.zipCode).val(value.zipId)
                    );
            });
        },
        error: function (event) {
            ShowErrorLabel("ERROR in ajax call(" + ajaxUrl + "): \n" + "Error : " + event.status + " - " + event.statusText);
        }
    });
```