# How can I set the initial value of Select2 when using AJAX?

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a select2 v4.0.0 being populated from an Ajax array. If I set the val of the select2 I can see via javascript debugging that it has selected the correct item (#3 in my case), however this is not shown in the select box, it is still showing the placeholder.
[image]

Whereas I should be seeing something like this:
[image]

In my form fields:

```html
<input name="creditor_id" type="hidden" value="3" />
<div class="form-group minimal form-gap-after">
    <span class="col-xs-3 control-label minimal">
        <label for="Creditor:">Creditor:</label>
    </span>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-8 pull-left select2-bootstrap-prepend">
            <select class="creditor_select2 input-xlarge form-control minimal select2 col-xs-8">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```js
var initial_creditor_id="3";
$(".creditor_select2").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/admin/api/transactions/creditorlist",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term,
                c_id: initial_creditor_id,
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    placeholder: "Search for a Creditor",
    width: "element",
    theme: "bootstrap",
    allowClear: true
}).on("select2:select", function (e) {
    var selected=e.params.data;
    if (typeof selected!=="undefined") {
        $("[name='creditor_id']").val(selected.creditor_id);
        $("#allocationsDiv").hide();
        $("[name='amount_cash']").val("");
        $("[name='amount_cheque']").val("");
        $("[name='amount_direct']").val("");
        $("[name='amount_creditcard']").val("");
    }
}).on("select2:unselecting", function (e) {
    $("form").each(function () {
        this.reset()
    });
    ("#allocationsDiv").hide();
    $("[name='creditor_id']").val("");
}).val(initial_creditor_id);
```

How can I make the select box show the selected item rather than the placeholder? Should I be sending this as part of the AJAX JSON response perhaps?

In the past, Select2 required an option called initSelection that was defined whenever a custom data source was being used, allowing for the initial selection for the component to be determined. This worked fine for me in v3.5.

Comment: How its possible? When i'm trying bind `select` with `ajax` it rises error, that option ajax its not allowed with select...

Comment: Hi,please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833778/ember-select-2-issue-while-using-type-ahead-with-ajax-queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting initial values on load with Select2 with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699641/setting-initial-values-on-load-with-select2-with-ajax)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You are doing most things correctly, it looks like the only problem you are hitting is that you are not triggering the `change` method after you are setting the new value. Without a `change` event, Select2 cannot know that the underlying value has changed so it will only display the placeholder. Changing your last part to

```
.val(initial_creditor_id).trigger('change');
```

Should fix your issue, and you should see the UI update right away.

---

This is assuming that you have an `<option>` already that has a `value` of `initial_creditor_id`. If you do not Select2, and the browser, will not actually be able to change the value, as there is no option to switch to, and Select2 will not detect the new value. I noticed that your `<select>` only contains a single option, the one for the placeholder, which means that you will need to create the new `<option>` manually.

```
var $option = $("<option selected></option>").val(initial_creditor_id).text("Whatever Select2 should display");
```

And then append it to the `<select>` that you initialized Select2 on. You may need to get the text from an external source, which is where `initSelection` used to come into play, which is still possible with Select2 4.0.0. Like a standard select, this means you are going to have to make the AJAX request to retrieve the value and then set the `<option>` text on the fly to adjust.

```
var $select = $('.creditor_select2');

$select.select2(/* ... */); // initialize Select2 and any events

var $option = $('<option selected>Loading...</option>').val(initial_creditor_id);

$select.append($option).trigger('change'); // append the option and update Select2

$.ajax({ // make the request for the selected data object
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/for/single/creditor/' + initial_creditor_id,
  dataType: 'json'
}).then(function (data) {
  // Here we should have the data object
  $option.text(data.text).val(data.id); // update the text that is displayed (and maybe even the value)
  $option.removeData(); // remove any caching data that might be associated
  $select.trigger('change'); // notify JavaScript components of possible changes
});
```

While this may look like a lot of code, this is *exactly how you would do it* for non-Select2 select boxes to ensure that all changes were made.

Comment: That almost works. The DataObject returned is likely to be an array of objects with a single item in it, so for a single item I probably need to return something like: `$option.text(data[0].text).val(data[0].id);` or if I am getting back an array of all of the possible options: `if (initial_creditor_id >0) {
                    var initial = jQuery.grep(data, function (selected) {
                        return selected.creditor_id == initial_creditor_id
                    });
                    $option.text(initial[0].text);
                    $option.val(initial[0].creditor_id);`

Comment: Any idea how to preselect multiple options for multi select boxes?

Comment: @user396404 the same concepts should apply, just pass a list of ids into `val()` instead of a single id. Or just append multiple `<option selected>` and that should be handled automatically.

Comment: select2 has the option to .select2("val", value); this should do exactly the same as you do only much shorter, am i right?

Comment: @JpHouten `select2('val')` is deprecated, but it previously worked the exact same as the first code snippet in this answer.

Comment: @KevinBrown Thank you, I guess you already fixed this issue for me in https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4035 (if thats you) I only added a new problem i stumbled across while heavily testing this.

Comment: I realize this answer is over a year old, but the documentation for Select2 for the FAQ question: "How can I set the initially selected options when using AJAX?" still points to this. I've attached a JSFiddle as a working example for v4.0.3

https://jsfiddle.net/57co6c95/

Comment: I need help with this! the docs redirected me here and now stuck! I'm using 4.0.3. I want to do for multiple one

Comment: There is a problem. What if I want to request more than just id and text? I have tried but the data option only getting the data for templateResult and ignore it for templateSelection. Any idea?

Comment: @ClearBoth I was able to find a solution with using templateSelection's and having an initial selection.  See my answer below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43942110/88732

Comment: @KevinBrown I think it would be awesome if Select2 had an option to fetch initial options by using the own select2's config during setup, as if the user had clicked the dropdown to show initial available options. In this example, the selected Id would be sent with the request to fetch this initial data, so the server could handle and load just the selected option. I think this would be better than making an ajax call manually, as the component would be already prepared to send the appropriate request data, transform the response and apply any templates.

Comment: Also, I tried this solution, but unfortunately after calling `$select.trigger('change');` the option is still with the *Loading...* text, even though `data.text` had exactly the text I wanted. Maybe this is no longer supported in **4.0.6**.

Comment: not working in my case ..val({{ $notice->pushNotifications[0]->employee_id }}).trigger('change');

Answer (score 35):

What I've done is more clean and needs to make two arrays :

- one contains a list of Object with id and a text (in my case its id and name, depending of your templateResult) (its what you get from ajax query)
- the second is only an array of ids (selection value)

I initialize select2 using the first array as data, and the second as the val.

An example function with as parameters a dict of id:name.

```
function initMyList(values) {
    var selected = [];
    var initials = [];

    for (var s in values) {
        initials.push({id: s, name: values[s].name});
        selected.push(s);
    }

    $('#myselect2').select2({
        data: initials,
        ajax: {
            url: "/path/to/value/",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term,
                    page: params.page || 1,
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                params.page = params.page || 1;

                return {
                    results: data.items,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
        placeholder: "Select none, one or many values",
        templateResult: function (item) { return item.name; },
        templateSelection: function (item) { return item.name; },
        matcher: function(term, text) { return text.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) != -1; },
    });

    $('#myselect2').val(selected).trigger('change');
}
```

You can feed the initials value using ajax calls, and use jquery promises to do the select2 initialization.

Comment: This is definitely the better way of doing it. Manipulating the DOM by adding `<option>` doesn't seem to be the most logical way to do it. This is how I do it in 4.0

Comment: @firebird631, your solution is brilliant, it works and very big thanks!

Comment: this is the cleanest solution i have seen so far

Comment: I will note that internally the `data` option is just generating `<option>` tags and adding them to the select. This answer doesn't cover how you handle cases where you need to go out to an API to get more information, but I guess that's a less typical case.

Comment: Hello with ajax I am not able to do it. When I send a list with two object there is no problem it tries to insert those two object but only one inserted. and already selected automatically. I never able to see two option, even I sent two item.

Comment: You are defying the whole meaning of using remote data fetching using query! 99.99% of the time people will use data fetching when they handle a lot of options and need to save traffic and memory, and your idea to pre-select few values is first to fetch everything and save that in memory...

Answer (score 11):

It's works for me ...

Don't use jQuery, only HTML: Create the **option value** you will display as **selected**.
If ID it's in **select2 data** it will selected automatically.

```
<select id="select2" name="mySelect2">
  <option value="mySelectedValue">
        Hello, I'm here!
  </option>
</select>
```

[Select2.org - Default Pre Selected values](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#default-pre-selected-values)

Comment: You are missing selected attribute. And this is not working well with custom rendering.

Comment: Question is using ajax. So this is unnecessary to suggest not using it. I have the same problem because of massive data, I use ajax to page it and not block the dom.

Answer (score 7):

The issue of being forced to `trigger('change')` drove me nuts, as I had custom code in the `change` trigger, which should only trigger when the user changes the option in the dropdown. IMO, change should not be triggered when setting an init value at the start.

I dug deep and found the following: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3620

**Example:**

`$dropDown.val(1).trigger('change.select2');`

Answer (score 7):

One scenario that I haven't seen people really answer, is how to have a preselection when the options are AJAX sourced, and you can select multiple. Since this is the go-to page for AJAX preselection, I'll add my solution here.

```
$('#mySelect').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: endpoint,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: [
            { // Each of these gets processed by fnRenderResults.
                id: usersId,
                text: usersFullName,
                full_name: usersFullName,
                email: usersEmail,
                image_url: usersImageUrl,
                selected: true // Causes the selection to actually get selected.
            }
        ],
        processResults: function(data) {

            return {
                results: data.users,
                pagination: {
                    more: data.next !== null
                }
            };

        }
    },
    templateResult: fnRenderResults,
    templateSelection: fnRenderSelection, // Renders the result with my own style
    selectOnClose: true
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a templateSelection and ajax, some of these other answers may not work.  It seems that creating a new `option` element and setting the `value` and `text` will not satisfy the template method when your data objects use other values than id and text.

Here is what worked for me:

```
$("#selectElem").select2({
  ajax: { ... },
  data: [YOUR_DEFAULT_OBJECT],
  templateSelection: yourCustomTemplate
}
```

Check out the jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/f8h1xnv4

In my case, I had to `processResults` in since my data did not contain the required `id` and `text` fields.  If you need to do this, you will also need to run your initial selection through the same function.  Like so:

```
$(".js-select2").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: SOME_URL,
    processResults: processData
  },
  data: processData([YOUR_INIT_OBJECT]).results,
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateSelection: myCustomTemplate
});

function processData(data) {
  var mapdata = $.map(data, function (obj) {      
    obj.id = obj.Id;
    obj.text = '[' + obj.Code + '] ' + obj.Description;
    return obj;
  });
  return { results: mapdata }; 
}

function myCustomTemplate(item) {
     return '<strong>' + item.Code + '</strong> - ' + item.Description;
}
```

Comment: FINALLY!!!!! Wow, that could not have been more frustrating!! I had been using "name" instead of "text" and it was killing me. I switched to the default "text" key and it's working perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For a simple and semantic solution i prefer to define the initial value in HTML, example:

```
<select name="myfield" data-placeholder="Select an option">
    <option value="initial-value" selected>Initial text</option>
</select>
```

So when i call `$('select').select2({ ajax: {...}});` the initial value is `initial-value` and its option text is `Initial text`.

My current Select2 version is [4.0.3](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases/tag/4.0.3), but i think it has a great compatibility with other versions.

Comment: I guess you are saving  not only a select value, but also a text to your database, so you can retrieve it like that... sheesh!

Comment: @ITDesigns.eu, I don't think so, the value sento to database is `initial-value` and the text `Initial text` act as a placeholder, it isn't sent to database. It is working in my application.

Comment: why would I need a placeholder instead of a real text *in the actual option*?!

Comment: @ITDesigns.eu, Select2 catches this info and mount itself

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4272
only this solved my problem.
even you set default value by option, you have to format the object, which has the text attribute and this is what you want to show in your option.
so, your format function have to use `||` to choose the attribute which is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

after spending a few hours searching for a solution, I decided to create my own. He it is:

```
 function CustomInitSelect2(element, options) {
            if (options.url) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: options.url,
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).then(function (data) {
                    element.select2({
                        data: data
                    });
                    if (options.initialValue) {
                        element.val(options.initialValue).trigger('change');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

And you can initialize the selects using this function:

```
$('.select2').each(function (index, element) {
            var item = $(element);
            if (item.data('url')) {
                CustomInitSelect2(item, {
                    url: item.data('url'),
                    initialValue: item.data('value')
                });
            }
            else {
                item.select2();
            }
        });
```

And of course, here is the html:

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="test1" data-url="mysite/load" data-value="123"></select>
```

Comment: Great idea for a generic initialisation procedure.

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest Solution ever**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#allowed_products").select2({
      ajax: {
          url: "/factory/get_product_list",
          dataType: 'json',
          type: "POST",
          // Additional AJAX parameters go here; see the end of this chapter for the full code of this example
          data: function (params) {
              var query = {
                  search: params.term,
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken: `${$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()}`
              }
              return query;
          },

          delay: 250,
          processResults: function(data) {
              return {
              results: data.products
              };
          },
          cache: true,
      },
      placeholder: "Select products",
      dropdownParent: $("#edit-product")
  })

  $.ajax({
        url: `/user/to/selectedProducts`,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "params": {}
        },
        success: function (data) {
            let selectElement = $("#allowed_products");   
            $.each(data.selected_products, function(index, obj) {
               var option = new Option(obj.text, obj.id, true, true);
               selectElement.append(option).trigger("change");
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label for="limit">Allowed Products</label>
<select id="allowed_products" class="select2 select2-multiple" multiple data-placeholder="Search product" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" name="product" required>
  <option value=""></option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Add the selected (default) value to the select2 dropdown as an option and mark then `selected` so that select2() considers it select and when by Ajax a new list of options of the dropdown is loaded, merges the new options with the already selected option.

Thus it causes no conflict with the already selected option.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer mainly because I can't comment above! I found it was the comment by @Nicki and her jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/57co6c95/, that eventually got this working for me.

Among other things, it gave examples of the format for the json needed. The only change I had to make was that my initial results were returned in the same format as the other ajax call so I had to use

```
$option.text(data[0].text).val(data[0].id);
```

rather than

```
$option.text(data.text).val(data.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create simple ajax combo with de initial seleted value for select2 4.0.3

```
<select name="mycombo" id="mycombo""></select>                   
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    selectMaker.create('table', 'idname', '1', $("#mycombo"), 2, 'type');                                
});
</script>
```

library .js

```
var selectMaker = {
create: function (table, fieldname, initialSelected, input, minimumInputLength = 3, type ='',placeholder = 'Select a element') {
    if (input.data('select2')) {
        input.select2("destroy");
    }
    input.select2({
        placeholder: placeholder,
        width: '100%',
        minimumInputLength: minimumInputLength,
        containerCssClass: type,
        dropdownCssClass: type,
        ajax: {
            url: 'ajaxValues.php?getQuery=true&table=' + table + '&fieldname=' + fieldname + '&type=' + type,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data.items, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.name,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
    if (initialSelected>0) {
        var $option = $('<option selected>Cargando...</option>').val(0);
        input.append($option).trigger('change'); // append the option and update Select2
        $.ajax({// make the request for the selected data object
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajaxValues.php?getQuery=true&table=' + table + '&fieldname=' + fieldname + '&type=' + type + '&initialSelected=' + initialSelected,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).then(function (data) {
            // Here we should have the data object
            $option.text(data.items[0].name).val(data.items[0].id); // update the text that is displayed (and maybe even the value)
            $option.removeData(); // remove any caching data that might be associated
            input.trigger('change'); // notify JavaScript components of possible changes
        });
    }
}
};
```

and the php server side

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['getQuery']) && isset($_GET['table']) && isset($_GET['fieldname'])) {
//parametros carga de petición
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);
$data = (object) $data;
if (isset($data->term)) {
    $term = pSQL($data->term);
}else{
    $term = '';
}
if (isset($_GET['initialSelected'])){
    $id =pSQL($_GET['initialSelected']);
}else{
    $id = '';
}
if ($_GET['table'] == 'mytable' && $_GET['fieldname'] == 'mycolname' && $_GET['type'] == 'mytype') {

    if (empty($id)){
        $where = "and name like '%" . $term . "%'";
    }else{
         $where = "and id= ".$id;
    }

    $rows = yourarrayfunctionfromsql("SELECT id, name 
                    FROM yourtable
                    WHERE 1 " . $where . "
                    ORDER BY name ");
}

$items = array("items" => $rows);
$var = json_encode($items);
echo $var;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me for multiple + template :

(my ajax return an additional parameter, "email")

```
// my template
var my_template_func = function (data){
    if( data.email )
        var email = data.email;
    else if( data.element )
        var email = data.element.dataset.email;
    var html = '<span><span>'+data.text+'</span> - <em>'+email+'</em></span>';
        return $(html);
};

// select2 init
$('.my-select').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '...',
        dataType: 'json',
    },
    templateResult: my_template_func,
    templateSelection: my_template_func,
});
```

Then either i set default option(s) in html

```
<option value="555" data-email="test@exemple.com" selected>Bob</option>
```

Or i add the option(s) with JS

```
// add option(s)
var option = new Option('Bob', 555, true, true);
option.dataset.email = 'test@exemple.com';
$('.my-select').append(option).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'm Using Select2 V 4.0.13**

I found a workable solution for the ones looking for selecting a specific option by `value`.

Note that I commented my ajax request because it's my personal webpage and StackOverflow is not allowed, but you can put your own request url in `data-requesturl` select attribute and uncomment ajax in js part. Remember to return array with `[{"id":"id","text":"text"}]` structure.

I used another ajax because I don't wanted select2 requests every search or paginate, that's a solution to get data before and use `transport` with server data.

The most important part is to put selected value in `data-value` select attribute, and then it will be selected.

```js
var ssTimerObj = {};

$('.SelectSearch').each(function () {
  var ssSelector = $(this),
      ssID = $(this).attr('id');

  if(!$(ssSelector).hasClass('Lazy')){
    $(ssSelector).select2({
      dropdownParent: $(ssSelector).parent(),
      allowClear: true
    });
  } else {
    ssTimerObj[ssID] = null;

    var requestURL = $(ssSelector).attr('data-requesturl'),
        requestParameters = $(ssSelector).attr('data-requestparameters'),
        placeholder = $(ssSelector).attr('data-placeholder'),
        value = $(ssSelector).attr('data-value'),
        pageSize = $(ssSelector).attr('data-pagesize');
     
    requestParameters = requestParameters === undefined ? '' : requestParameters;
    requestParameters = requestParameters.replace(/'/g, '"');
    requestParameters = requestParameters !== '' ? JSON.parse(requestParameters) : {};
    placeholder = placeholder === undefined ? '' : placeholder;
    value = value === undefined ? '' : value;
    pageSize = pageSize === undefined ? 0 : pageSize;
    pageSize = parseInt(pageSize, 10);
    
    data = JSON.parse('[{"id":"nsalazar","text":"Nelly Salazar Mori"},{"id":"mtriguero","text":"Marta Triguero Consentino"},{"id":"ddiaz","text":"David D\u00edaz De Mier"},{"id":"vlopez","text":"Ver\u00f3nica  L\u00f3pez  Mart\u00edn"},{"id":"esanchez","text":"Eduardo S\u00e1nchez Rodr\u00edguez"},{"id":"mgraca","text":"M\u00f3nica Graca "}]');
    
    /*$.ajax({
      data: requestParameters,
      url: requestURL,
      type: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function () {},
      success: function (data) {
    */
        var dataSelect = data;
    
        $(ssSelector).html('');

        $(ssSelector).select2({
          dropdownParent: $(ssSelector).parent(),
          allowClear: true,
          placeholder: placeholder,
          ajax: {
            delay: 250,
            transport: function(params, success, failure) {
              var term = params.data.term != undefined ? params.data.term.toLowerCase() : '';
              var page = params.data.page != undefined ? params.data.page : 1;

              if (ssTimerObj[ssID]){
                clearTimeout(ssTimerObj[ssID]);
              }

              ssTimerObj[ssID] = setTimeout(function(){
                ssTimerObj[ssID] = null;
                var results = dataSelect // your base array here
                    .filter(function(f){
                      // your custom filtering here.
                      return f.text !== undefined ? f.text.toLowerCase().includes(term) : true;
                    })
                    .map(function(f){
                      // your custom mapping here.
                      return { id: f.id, text: f.text}; 
                    });

                var paged = results.slice((page -1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);

                var options = {
                      results: paged,
                      pagination: {
                        more: results.length >= page * pageSize
                      }
                    };
                success(options);
              }, params.delay);
            }
          }
        });
        
        if(value !== ''){
          var selectedData = dataSelect.filter(function(f){
                return f.id !== undefined ? (f.id === value ? true : false) : false;
              });

          if(selectedData.length > 0){
            $(ssSelector).select2("trigger", "select", {
              data: { id: selectedData[0]['id'], text: selectedData[0]['text'] }
            });
          }
        }
    /*
    },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
    */
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="row m-3">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label for="User">Select Valued</label>
    <select class="form-control SelectSearch Lazy" name="User" id="User" data-placeholder="--Seleccione--" data-requesturl="[RequestURL for example: /GetUserList]" data-pagesize="60" data-value="nsalazar">
      <option value="">Cargando...</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-2">
    <label for="User2">Select Normal</label>
    <select class="form-control SelectSearch Lazy" name="User2" id="User2" data-placeholder="--Seleccione--" data-requesturl="[RequestURL for example: /GetUserList]" data-pagesize="60">
      <option value="">Cargando...</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

Hi was almost quitting this and go back to select 3.5.1. But finally I got the answer!

```
$('#test').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a Country",
    minimumResultsForSearch: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: '...',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: function (params) {
                var queryParameters = {
                    q: params.term
                }
                return queryParameters;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data.items
            };
        }
    }
});

var option1 = new Option("new",true, true);

$('#status').append(option1);

$('#status').trigger('change');
```

Just be sure that the new option is one of the select2 options. I get this by a json.

Comment: Hi  - what is '#status' ? shouldthat be '#test' ?