# Programmatically set data to ajaxified select2 4.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I use select 2 (v4.0) with an ajax option and it works well.

Is there any possibility to programmatically set the selected value of the select (without user click and search)?

**UPDATE**

Currently I am doing reinit of select2 with `initSelection` option, but maybe there is another way to do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select2 4.0.0 initial value with Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316586/select2-4-0-0-initial-value-with-ajax)

Comment: I didn't find a solution in that question. creating `option` and triggering `change` event doesn't work on select2 4.0.

Comment: Please share some code that you are currently using then ([Stack Snippets preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-select2/info)), so we can help determine what the issue is.

Comment: I am using standart `select2({ ajax: ... })` init. I tried `$select.append($option).trigger('change');` and other possible solutions and they do not work. The only way I found is to call init method with all options every time I need to add value to the select programmatically.