# select2 initial values are being replaced when a new value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Below is my code for a [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) box.  I need values (tags) already assigned to a record to show initially, this is represented by the `AAA` and `BBB` values.  Then I need to ajax in a list of values to pick from if they want to add new values (tags) to the already existing ones.  Everything works except when they select a new value (tag) to add it replaces the existing ones, they disappear.  I need them to stay.

[image]

```
<select class="myTags" style="width:100%" multiple="multiple"></select>
<script>
    function formatResults(item) {
        if (item.loading) return 'Loading...';
        return '<div style="font-size:100%;">'+
                    '<div style="padding:5px;">'+
                        '<span style="background-color:##e4e4e4; color:##000000; border:1px solid ##aaa; padding:5px;">'+
                            item.tag+
                        '</span>'+
                        '<span style="padding:5px;">'+
                            '&nbsp;&nbsp;x&nbsp;&nbsp;'+item.popularity+
                        '</span>'+
                        '<p style="margin-bottom:0px;">'+
                        item.description+
                        '</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
    }

    function formatSelection(item) {
        return item.tag;
    }

    jQuery(".myTags").select2({
        placeholder: "add a tag, max 20 tags",
        maximumSelectionLength: 20,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        templateResult: formatResults,
        templateSelection: formatSelection,
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var data = [{ "tag": "AAA", "id": "111" },{ "tag": "BBB", "id": "222" }];
            callback(data);
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let select2's custom formatter work
        ajax: {
            url: "tags.cfc?method=json_get_valtags",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: jQuery.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.UNID,
                            tag: item.TAG,
                            description: item.DESCRIPTION,
                            popularity: item.POPULARITY
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  [This SO post was very similar to what I needed but I had to tweak it some for my specific scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38141552/3112803).

(1) I had to add the select2 `data` option...

```
data: [{ "tag": "AAA", "id": "112233" },{ "tag": "BBB", "id": "11223344" }],
```

(2) Then I removed the entire `initSelection` function from the options.

(3) Then I added this at the bottom after the select2 initialization...

```
jQuery(".myTags").val([112233,11223344]).trigger('change');
```

So this is the end result...

```
jQuery(".myTags").select2({
    data: [{ "tag": "aaa", "id": "112233" },{ "tag": "bbb", "id": "11223344" }],
    placeholder: "add a tag, max 20 tags",
    maximumSelectionLength: 20,
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    templateResult: formatResults,
    templateSelection: formatSelection,
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let select2's custom formatter work
    ajax: {
        url: "tags.cfc?method=json_get_valtags",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: jQuery.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.UNID,
                        tag: item.TAG,
                        description: item.DESCRIPTION,
                        popularity: item.POPULARITY
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});

jQuery(".cmprotags").val([112233,11223344]).trigger('change');
```