# Can I set the query string parameters in Select2 when using AJAX data source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am running into a "weird" (maybe not) case where I need to pass the parameters through the URL instead of send them as `q`. Take a look at the following example from [docs](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax):

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      params.page = params.page || 1;

      return {
        results: data.items,
        pagination: {
          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
        }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  ...
});
```

In the above example `params.term` is sent to the server and you can use any mechanism to get it and do what you want to do.

In my case I am sending the search term to an API endpoint. The API is expecting something like the following example:

```
http://someurl?slug=56&title=56&description=56&content=56
```

In other words:

```
'http://someurl?slug='+params.term+'&title='+params.term+'&description='+params.term+'&content='+params.term
```

As you many notice `params.term` become the value to be sent on the URL for the API.

But I don't know how to achieve this with Select2. I have been looking for some info but without success, this is what I have been looked so far:

- https://select2.github.io/options.html
- https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3548
- https://select2.github.io/options-old.html
- [Select2 4.0.0 initial value with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316586/select2-4-0-0-initial-value-with-ajax#30328989)

But none say anything about what I need. Does any have any idea in how to achieve this?

Comment: Query string you want doesn't seem to match api docs https://developer.github.com/v3/search/. The `q` in your data seems correct

Comment: @charlietfl that's just an example, doesn't mean it's the right URL I just copied and paste from the example to keep the post on the same page, if it's confusing I can change it to something else

Comment: sure it's confusing when you use query params that are made up or show an api url like github that is well documented

Comment: Now have no idea what relationship of the `params` in plugin are to your `slug, title, description` etc but your `data` object properties should match those property names

Comment: @charlietfl please re-read the post, it's better now? Let's cleanup this comments when you is satisfied with the OP :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the data object to reflect the properties you want to have in the query string:

```
data: function (params) {
  return {
    slug: params.term, 
    description: params.term,
    content: params.term
  };
},
```

Double check in dev tools network that this is indeed done as a GET otherwise try adding `type:'GET'` to the ajax options

Comment: Great, you're the best it works and I didn't need to add the `type: 'GET'` toe the request. Thanks