# Initialize select2 with data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have an API [`sewatanah/getprovinsi`](https://ip.jordkris.com/api/sewatanah/getprovinsi) with the GET method and it will return:

```json
[{"id":"0","text":""},{"id":"11","text":"ACEH"},{"id":"12","text":"SUMATERA UTARA"}, ...]
```

It can be filtered if there is a `q` param in that URL based on the substring of `text` property.

For example, API [`sewatanah/getprovinsi?q=ac`](https://ip.jordkris.com/api/sewatanah/getprovinsi?q=ac) will return:

```json
[{"id":"11","text":"ACEH"}, ...]
```

I implement `select2` library like this:

```js
$('.provinsi').select2({
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: '-',
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://ip.jordkris.com/api/sewatanah/getprovinsi',
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        q: params.term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(prop) {
          return {
            id: prop.id,
            text: prop.nama
          }
        })
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }
});

$('.provinsi').val('11').trigger('change');
```

```css
.provinsi {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.6-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.6-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>Provinsi</label>
  <select class="provinsi"></select>
</div>
```

The problem is I can't initialize the value with this:

```js
$('.provinsi').val('11').trigger('change');
```

I know it can't be done because data only is retrieved from an Ajax call while `.val('11')` didn't call Ajax. How can I solve this?

Comment: Which version of select2 are you using?

Comment: @Benilson `select2` version 4.

Comment: @Benilson specifically `select2 v4.0.6-rc.0`.

Comment: Hi, if you know what you need to keep selected you can add option tag in your select-tag with that option selected and when searching happens it will change automatically .

Comment: Hi @Swati, thanks for your advice. Can you give me an example for that?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316586/how-can-i-set-the-initial-value-of-select2-when-using-ajax) post for same.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example of this problem and steps of reproduction so we can play around with it?

Comment: @LajosArpad Sure, you can try [this API](https://ip.jordkris.com/api/sewatanah/getprovinsi?q=ac).

Comment: Thanks, Jordy, but I would be interested to see an editable reproducible example, a jsfiddle or the like. It is probably not very difficult for you to make such an example, but such an example would significantly raise my confidence that I tackle the exact problem you have.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, I have added the working fiddle in the updated question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add option tag with selected="selected" attribute.

```
  <select class="provinsi">
    <option value="31" selected="selected">DKI JAKARTA</option>
  </select>
```

`$('.provinsi').val('11').trigger('change');` It is not necessary.

```js
$('.provinsi').select2({
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: '-',
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://ip.jordkris.com/api/sewatanah/getprovinsi',
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        q: params.term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(prop) {
          return {
            id: prop.id,
            text: prop.nama
          }
        })
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }
});

// $('.provinsi').val('11').trigger('change');
```

```css
.provinsi {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.6-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.6-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>Provinsi</label>
  <select class="provinsi">
    <option value="31" selected="selected">DKI JAKARTA</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. But is there a way to achieve this with javascript only?

Comment: You can use Farhan Islam answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the solution, but I turn away to use another solution with predefined data from Ajax call, then initialize the value.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://ip.jordkris.com/api/sewatanah/getprovinsi',
  success: (res) => {
    $('.provinsi').append($.map(res, (obj) => {
      return $('<option>').val(obj.id).text(obj.nama);
    }));
    $('.provinsi').select2();
    $('.provinsi').val('31').trigger('change');
  },
  error: (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.6-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.6-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>Provinsi</label>
  <select class="provinsi"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of a `select` to something that's not an `option`. You need to make sure that your desired `option` exists first and then you can set your value. In the modified snippet below I have checked whether the `select` has the `option` you desired and if not, then it's created before we change the value. I might be misunderstanding the question, please let me know whether this is helpful and what further changes/information you may need.

```js
$('.provinsi').select2({
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: '-',
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://ip.jordkris.com/api/sewatanah/getprovinsi',
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        q: params.term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(prop) {
          return {
            id: prop.id,
            text: prop.nama
          }
        })
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }
});

let v = {key: 11, text: 'ACEH'};
let provinsi = $('.provinsi');
if (!provinsi.find(`option[value=${v.key}]`).length) {
    provinsi.append(`<option value=${v.key}>${v.text}</option>`)
    provinsi.val('11').trigger('change');
}
```

```css
.provinsi {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.6-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.6-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>Provinsi</label>
  <select class="provinsi">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The `innerHTML` of the 11's options is wrong. I want to detect what suitable `innerHTML` is when setting the value with `11` or `12`, etc.

Comment: @Jordy what should the innerHTML be instead?

Comment: `ACEH` for `11`