# Programmatically setting value in Select2 with AJAX data retrieval when minimum input length is defined

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a select2 which is defined with minimum input length and ajax call (remote data) to retrieve data from server based on user input.

```
$('#itemList').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        // AJAX configuration here
    }
});
```

When a user selecting a previously saved record to update, I need to set the option programmatically so the user can see it and if needed, can change. I have tried setting the value and also appending as a new option, but nothing seems to work.

**Attempt 1 :**

```
$('#itemList').val(value).trigger('change');
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
var option = new Option(text, value, true, true);
$("#itemList").append(option).trigger('change');
```

Also tried [this](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2)

**Attempt 3:**

```
$.ajax({
     url: link,
     dataType: "json",
     type: "GET",
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     async: false,
     processData: false,
     cache: false
}).then(function (data) {

    // create the option and append to Select2
    var option = new Option(text, value, true, true);
    $("#itemList").append(option).trigger('change');

    // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
    $("#itemList").trigger({
        type: 'select2:select',
        params: {
            data: data
        }
    });
});
```

Nothing seems to work.

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of select2 are you using?

Comment: select2 4.0.6-rc.1

Comment: See if the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199548/initialize-select2-with-data-from-ajax-call) helps you.

Comment: Setting the initial value does not solve the problem. As the requirement is for update option, the value should be set dynamically based on the previously saved record.