# How to add copy paste capabilities to Select2 with AJAX data source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, django-select2

Currently, I'm working on the Admin side of a Django 4.2 site.
The current version of Django, uses Select2 to handle FK fields in forms.

I have the need to add copy paste capabilities to those forms, so they can copy data from an excel and paste it and fill a collection of Select2s. But it seems that selecting the data from a remote sourced data it's more tricky than expected.

According to the [Select2's documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)

> For Select2 controls that receive their data from an AJAX source, using `.val()` will not work.

Instead, they recommend fetching the data yourself and adding it as a new option.

```js
// Set up the Select2 control
$('#mySelect2').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/students'
    }
});

// Fetch the preselected item, and add to the control
var studentSelect = $('#mySelect2');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/students/s/' + studentId
}).then(function (data) {
    // create the option and append to Select2
    var option = new Option(data.full_name, data.id, true, true);
    studentSelect.append(option).trigger('change');

    // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
    studentSelect.trigger({
        type: 'select2:select',
        params: {
            data: data
        }
    });
});
```

Since the Select2 already knows how to fetch it's own data, since it already does for the autocomplete, duplicating whats already implemented seems to me like a waste of time.

```html
<select name="form-0-multiplex_index" id="id_form-0-multiplex_index" class="admin-autocomplete" data-ajax--cache="true" data-ajax--delay="250" data-ajax--type="GET" data-ajax--url="/admin/autocomplete/" data-app-label="sequencing" data-model-name="uploadedlibrary" data-field-name="multiplex_index" data-theme="admin-autocomplete" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder="" lang="en">
```

So, in a nutshell, my question is. **How to programmatically search and select the first result on a Select2 input with Ajax fetched data given a string from the clipboard without having to re-implement it from scrath?** (Or at the very least, reuse the parameters already present on the dom).

Comment: See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199548/initialize-select2-with-data-from-ajax-call/76227500) help you.